# What is the difference between .global and .globl?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

For example, I've seen `_start` as `.global _start` and `.globl _start`. It seems like I can just use them interchangeably. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: You forgot to mention which assembler you use. For the GNU assembler consult the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html) which says: _Both spellings are accepted, for compatibility with other assemblers._ So there is no difference.

Comment: I think `.global` might have been added later.  Probably old versions of GAS only accept `.globl`.  x86 asm code in glibc and Linux (the kernel) always uses `.globl`, IIRC.

Comment: @Jester Why is it a comment and not an answer? It is the answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

They are the same. In fact, the LLVM assembler in *MCParser/AsmParser.cpp* lexes them as DK_GLOBL and DK_GLOBAL

```
DirectiveKindMap[".globl"] = DK_GLOBL;
DirectiveKindMap[".global"] = DK_GLOBAL;
```

but then parses them as the same attribute.

```
case DK_GLOBL:
case DK_GLOBAL:
    return parseDirectiveSymbolAttribute(MCSA_Global);
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to also link the GAS documentation (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html) which says they're synonyms.  LLVM's directive handling is basically aiming for GAS compatibility, I think.

Comment: `binutils` source also confirms that they're the same, although that source looks very different to the LLVM source code above. Both symbols are handled identically; by calling a function named `s_globl`: `{"global", s_globl, 0},
  {"globl", s_globl, 0},`